# Formulário Many to Many rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Gostaria de saber como fazer um *form* **many to many** em rails.

Aqui estão o meus models:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :notices, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :internships, dependent: :destroy
end

class Internship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :enterprise
  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
end
```

Também tenho uma outra dúvida, com relação ao mesmo assunto. Supondo que eu tenha 3 cursos relacionados ao estágio.

Quando eu utilizar a *action update* e atualizar os cursos relacionados para 2, o rails automaticamente vai excluir essa relação que não está mais presente na atualização?

Answer (score 0):

Para Many To Many no seu caso poderia ser:

> #### course
>
> has_and_belongs_to_many :internships, :join_table => :course_internships
>
> #### internship
>
> has_many :course
>
> #### course_internship
>
> belongs_to :courses
>
> belongs_to :internships

Na tabela course_internships teria 3 campos, que são:

> #### course_internships
>
> id
>
> courses_id
>
> internships_id

Talvez isso te ajude no many to many!